# payment gateway(No flutter SDK) integrate flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, payment-gateway

I'm working on integrating a payment gateway into my Flutter mobile app. However, the payment gateway doesn't have an Flutter SDK available.

I've reached a point where I'm not sure how to proceed. Here's what I have so far:

- First, I send a "Payment Request" to the payment gateway.
  In response, the payment gateway provides me with a "transaction redirect URL".
  Once I have the redirect URL
- I capture it and open it in a Flutter WebView.

At this stage, I need help figuring out how to manage the rest of the payment process. Here are the steps I'm unsure about:

- After opening the payment gateway's page in the WebView, I'm not sure how to handle the subsequent steps.

Payment gateway details:

- Documentation : https://developer.onepay.lk
- API details: https://github.com/onepay-srilanka

Comment: The transaction-redirect-url seems to be one that's called with success/failure details of how the transaction went. The documentation is very weak on that site.

Comment: @Srikanth true. But, transaction-redirect-url is for payment page. 
Can get web page status using flutter WebView widget?

Comment: I'm not sure. Should expt or raise an issue on their github to get their process.

Answer (score 0):

I do see the framework on android and ios platform from their github repos. You should create your own flutter package and wrap both ios and android payment framework. You can see this example https://github.com/wamynobe/momo.vn